# jQuery equivalent for getElementsByClassName('name')[n]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any jQuery equivalent similar to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('para')[2].css("color","red");
});
```

for the code below

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('para')[2].style.color = "red";
```

```html
<p class="para">Content</p>
<p class="para">Content</p>
<p class="para">Content</p>
<p class="para">Content</p>
<p class="para">Content</p>
<p class="para">Content</p>
<p class="para">Content</p>
<p class="para">Content</p>
<p class="para">Content</p>
<p class="para">Content</p>
```

I want the CSS to be applied to the nth paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `.eq` if you want to access a specific `jQuery` element from a list of matched stuff:

`$(".para").eq(2).css("color","red");`

Edit: The dot notation, `.para`, is functionally equivalent to `getElementsByClassName("para")`

Comment: Darn! 10 seconds too late!

Comment: to get the actual DOM element underneath the jQuery element, use `get()` after `eq()` like this: `$(".para").eq(2).get(0).style.color = "red";`

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery alternative could be crafted as follows. Note that `nth-of-type` is not zero index based

```
$('p.para:nth-of-type(3)').css('color', 'red')
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sk0mktb1/)

Comment: This won't produce the same results if there any another `<p>` sibling preceding the list of `.para` paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use n-th child to set the style accordingly

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".para:nth-child(2)" ).css("color","red");
});
```

Comment: This won't produce the same results if there are any another siblings preceding the list of `.para` paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally use the [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) for this:

```
$('.para:eq(2)').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Note, however, that the `.eq()` filter mentioned by @AdamKewley is meant to give better performance.